# Como buscar valores de outras planilhas no mesmo XSLX usando PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Estou fazendo uma importação de produtos onde eu primeiro gero um modelo.
O arquivo modelo vem com quatro planilhas:

1. Worksheet -> planilha padrão para preenchimento dos dados do produto
2. Ambiente -> Lista de ambientes cadastrados no banco de dados.
3. Categorias -> Lista de categorias cadastradas no banco de dados.
4. Cores -> Lista de cores cadastradas no banco de dados.

Na planilha 1 é possível selecionar os dados das demais planilhas em uma combobox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa combobox do print vem da planilha 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que eu preciso:**

Usando PhpSpreadsheet (preferencialmente), eu preciso ler a planilha (já está feito), e buscar o ID do ambiente selecionado na planilha de ambientes, o id da categoria na planilha de categorias, e o id da cor na planilha de cores.

**Existe alguma forma de pegar essa informação?**

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi correndo um loop em cada planilha secundária jogando os dados em array.
Na hora de adicionar no banco, busco no array os ids que preciso e deu certo.
Talvez não seja a melhor forma (tenho quase certeza disso rs.), mas funcionou.